# How to convert File in byte array[] and store in database using Angular & ASP.Net Core?

Tags: c#, sql-server, angular, file-upload, asp.net-core

I am new in angular and being stuck to do File-upload in angular

Technologies : Angular, ASP.Net Core, Sqlserver

I need to add file-upload feature in my Angular application where services are in ASP.Net Core and in Services fileupload datatype is in Byte[]

I have form like Below
[image]

I need to save all data in database on click of Save button with convert file in byte[] and store in database

Thanks you Guys in advance

Comment: what have you tried in this regard? have you written any code?

Comment: This isn't the first time this question has been asked here in SO. Do your research first and try it yourself so when you ask next time it would be more specific.

Comment: @ r wank, No i did not written any code. i search many sample but its save file in particular location but i want to convert file in byte[] and store in database

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you don't need to convert any thing at ui side simply you can use `formData` and `HttpClient` to send binary data(files) to api.

this is a simple example

template

```
<input id="file" type="file"  (change)="fileChange($event.target.files)" />
```

component

```
export class FileUploadComponenet {

constractor(private httpClient:HttpClient){}

public fileChange(files:any[]) {

    if (files && files.length > 0) {
     let file = files[0];
     let formData = new FormData();
     formData.append('file', file);
     this.httpClient.post(url,formData).subscribe(res => console.log('File Uploaded ...');
    }  

  }
}
```

[File Upload Component in Angular](https://malcoded.com/posts/angular-file-upload-component-with-express)

Comment: When you do it like this, how do the other fields get sent if that is a new formdata.